# I want to get data from multiple appended rows in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am appending rows through jQuery. Now I need to get data from all appended rows. How I can achieve this?

```
$(function () {
  $('#cli').on('change', function () {
    var form = $('#edit-product');
    var x = $('#edit-product').serializeArray();
    var attributecolor = $(this).val(); //get value
    var configsku = $('#configsku').val(); //get value
    var configprice = $(this).val(); //get value
    var configqty = $(this).val(); //get value
    // Append data into #results div

    $("p1").append("<tr class='dop'><td>" + attributecolor + "</td><td><input type='text' name='configsku' id='configsku' placeholder='Add New Sku'></td><td><input type='text' name='configqty' id='configqty'  placeholder='Stock'></td><td><input type='text' tname='price' id='configprice' name='configprice' placeholder='Enter Price'></td><td><input type='text' name='sp-price' placeholder='Enter Special Price\'></td><td class='text-right'><i class='far fa-trash-alt del-table-add-sku'></i></td><br/></tr>");
    //$.post('Testsave.php', {configsku: configsku}, function(data){
    //$('#results').html(data);
  })

})
```

[image]

Comment: Yes Sinto i want to get data from appended rows.I am using post method.its four variable like color,sku,price and quantity.

Comment: Acutally, there is no value in what you are appending. So only after appending & entering values to those input field, you will get the required values to do ajax post. After entering values you have to submit it by clicking a button & on js a `.onClick()` function will fetch value and post o ajax

Comment: Yes i can get one value but when i have multiple append rows i think data will be in array.Plz have a look image

Comment: are you appending html with values or later adding value through interface

Comment: I will first enter value in fields and then on submit data will be post.Fields are appending empty and will be fill by customer.thats okay

Comment: so on submitting you need to fetch values & do the rest by ajax.